# size on disk is too less than actual size

Tags: windows, partitioning, ssd, disk-space

[image]

Thıs was happened when someone tried to transfer photos from his mobile device to my computer. Every single file is taking 13GB of size, and literally 8kb on disk I am using Windows 10 and have an 120Gb ssd. I had low free space about 10gb before this transfer. My question is, is it possible to recover or use these images, how do i deal with these. Are these files corrupted.

Comment: I suggest that you check the disk for errors: 1) In Windows Explorer, find drive C: 2) Right-click drive C: and choose "Properties". 3) Select the "Tools" tab. 4) Click the "Check" button. 6) Click the "Scan drive" text. 7) Wait for it to finish.

Comment: already did, no errors found.

Comment: I wonder if they are sparse files. If you run `attrib IMG_20200218_170525.jpg` from a command prompt in that directory, what does it tell you?

Comment: it prints the path of the file

Comment: Are there no letters like "A" or "P" before the path?

Comment: no just a full path, but with some tabs or spaces after.

Comment: Do you have another disk with at least 13GB free space that you could copy the file to? Then see if it is all zero bytes with a hex editor. I suggest copying it to another drive first so that it won't suddenly try to take up 13GB on your OS disk.

Comment: Note: I am expecting the files to be unusable.

Comment: it is mostly zeros. But at last hundred or so lines  are  not zero

Comment: It is not looking good. What happens when you try to open the file? Is there a part of an image, or will it not open?

Comment: does not open at all. in hex editor it shows that it is only zeros from 0 x 00 00 00 00 h to 3 x 44 a0 1a 90 h. so all these images probably corrupted at first place.,

Comment: If the mobile device was using something like a Micro SD card to store the images, and the root problem was that card, then you could use something like [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to recover what can be recovered from the card. Just guessing.

Comment: it wasnt in sd card. i will check whats going on in phone now. thank you for helping.